# RegEx expression for removing duplicates and all numbers and brackets

Tags: php, regex

So if I have a string that looks like this:

```
{1}{G}{G}{U}{U}{W}
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
GUW
```

I currently have this as my regex:

```
/(.)(?=.*\1)[^GUW]/
```

I also would like to pick the characters that would be used. In this case, 'GUW'.

Comment: What is the programming environment?

Comment: It's php. I updated the tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use 2 capture groups, where you would optionally repeat backreference to group 1 value (with the curly's) and use a replacement with group 2 that has the value inside the curly's.

The character class `[GUW]` matches one of the listed chars to be matched.

The dot after the `|` would match any other character to be removed.

```
(\{([GUW])})\1*|.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fa5NbE/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/DELOs)

For example:

```
$re = '/(\{([GUW])})\1*|./';
$str = '{1}{G}{G}{U}{U}{W}';
$result = preg_replace($re, '$2', $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
GUW
```